# Ruby select data from string via template, as php preg_match do

Tags: php, ruby, preg-match

i'm new to rails, and i want to know, how to change such php code to ruby, to select some code from html code:

in php i have

```
preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*)" />#U',$page,$match);
```

what i do must write, to have equivalent in ruby? Sorry i didn't have too much time, to read all ruby doc's, i need it only for one purpose...

maybe something like:

```
str.scan(/#<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*)" />#U/)
```

or how?
Help me to translate this php code to ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .match method. Doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match

Example:

```
[1] pry(main)> x = /<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*)" \/>/.match '#<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="ololo" />'
=> #<MatchData
 "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"ololo\" />"
 1:"ololo">
[2] pry(main)> x[1]
=> "ololo"
```

Comment: hi, but how to do, if i have for example such code: <img class="LBD_CaptchaImage" id="c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_ctl00_cp_botdetectcaptcha_CaptchaImage" src="/Uslugi/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&amp;c=c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_ctl00_cp_botdetectcaptcha&amp;t=6ca0a0dcb29446d6bb7c7549b06abff0" alt="CAPTCHA">    and i need to select part 6ca0a0dcb29446d6bb7c7549b06abff0 ? sorry i'm not so good in regex, also i will accept you answer...

Comment: In this case you can use regex like /(;|"|&)t\=([a-z0-9]+)/

Comment: also maybe you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830346/get-image-from-url-with-cookies-in-ruby ?

Comment: i must seperate in so: BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&amp;c=c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_c‌​tl00_cp_botdetectcaptcha&amp;t=(here could be letters, numbers, also one more = or &)", so all, what is after BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&amp;c=c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_c‌​tl00_cp_botdetectcaptcha&amp;t=  and till " is reached. Thank you... i'll wait)

Comment: maybe /amp\;t\=([a-z0-9]+)/ ?

Comment: no no, becouse i have it some times, as write below... first part must be BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&amp;c=c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_c‌​tl00_cp_bot‌​detectcaptcha&amp;t=   and then ([a-z0-9]+)/

Comment: you have only one param 'amp;t=', i think that should be enough.

Comment: Чувак) там в коде есть ещё в одном месте тоже самое, amp;t=  только вот начало другое, а потому оно берёт первое, а так не должно быть)

Comment: мне нужно так, как я сказал, фильтр по первой части должен быть

Comment: /BotDetectCaptcha.*amp\;t\=([a-z0-9]+)/

Comment: Да, ваше последне сообщение "рулит") Но как быть если к примеру у меня идёт BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&c=c_uslugi_rejestracjaterminu_ctl00_cp_botdetectcaptcha&t=ceb333cfdad64338aa776ffa7bac2dc8&d=1379332603204  т.е. есть ещё и &d=  оно восприймет это? т.е. до окончания кавычки?

Comment: Да и вообще, почитай хоть про регекспы на википедии, что бы иметь представление, что я написал.